# How is the .NET event, Application.OnIdle, coded in Win32?

Tags: .net, winapi, events

How is the .NET event, Application.OnIdle, coded in Win32? (i.e. What is going on behind the scenes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic Win32 message loop is something like this:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

There is also a [`PeekMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943(v=VS.85).aspx) function that tests to see whether a message is available. With that, you can modify the message loop as:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    do {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    } while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE));
    onIdle();
}
```

The above loop will call the translate/dispatch while there are still messages available to process, then when there are no more it will call `onIdle()`. Then it returns to the outer loop to call `GetMessage()` again to wait for the next message.

Note that this is one possible way to implement onIdle functionality in Win32. I don't know whether this is the same way .NET does it.

Comment: A seemingly plausible solution.  Thank Greg.  Also found this thread: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32039981/win32-equivalent-of-onidle.aspx